# How to read vim's key meaning in document

Tags: vim

I'm trying to understand the following vim help.(:help Voom)

```
<C-Up>, <C-Down> move node or a range of sibling nodes Up/Down.
<C-Left>, <C-Right> move nodes Left/Right (promote/demote).
(If the above CTRL mappings are not recognized by your Vim, you can also move
nodes Up/Down/Left/Right with <LocalLeader>u/d/l/r .)
```

The C-Up may means Ctrl-Up.  But it can NOT work. (I don't know why).
But, what's the  means?  It means `<localLeader>+u`  will get the same result as C-UP.
I don't know what's the key of `<LocalLeader>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `:help <LocalLeader>`, but: `<LocalLeader>` is whatever key you've set the `maplocalleader` variable to, or backslash if if you haven't set it.

Answer (score 0):

By default localleader is mapped to <kbd>\</kbd> (backslash)

Answer (score 0):

The `<c-xx>` combinations do all refer to `<ctrl-xx>` keys.  But those keys are not mapped properly by most terminals.  So you can use those combinations in gvim, but not in terminal vim.